# Schedule for learning Php & Programming

Tags: php, pseudocode

**Short Version**

I started learning Php with no programming experience. Books,tutorials concentrate on creating web pages and showing you built in functions etc. but don't show you how to PROGRAM (i.e. from problem create pseudo-code, create algorithms etc. which are creative processes). How would you recommend balancing learning Php together with PROGRAMMING?

**Long Winded Version**

I decided two months ago to learn Web-Programming with the goal of becoming a freelance web-programmer asap(urgently need a source of income). I want to be able to start earning something in a few months and building up professionalism with experience and learning over the years (I have seen many times on SO that it takes 10 years to become a GOOD programmer but no one said it take 10 years to start earning with programming).  I had no background except simple tinkering with C++ 15 years ago. I was considering a course that starts off with teaching c++ and oop intensively afterwards moving to php and mysql. However the people I spoke to told me that it is too longwinded and I should dive straight into Php using books which is what I am doing.

BUT I soon realized that while the book is teaching me Php very well explaining all the example scripts etc. and I know how to understand Php and copy the scripts for my own purposes it doesn't teach how to Program i.e. think through a problem, convert it into an appropriate algorithm, decide how to break up code into functions(encapsulation) etc. and I was just marveling at the solutions provided without learning the creative process myself. Then I bought Problem Solving in C++ by Walter Savitch which after reading through it began to open my eyes to pseudo-code etc. The book also has about 50 exercises for every chapter precisely to get you to create your own functions etc. and I was sometimes wishing that I could drop everything and just work through the book till I learn the process of Programming! (I saw on SO people recommending CodeComplete and a lot of other books on this topic - what do you say about this book?)

My question is how should I structure my learning to learn Php and Programming? 
At the moment I am finding myself in an infinite loop of spending a little time on Php, a little bit on Programming, another bit on StackOverflow and another bit learning Touch-Typing and another bit tinkering around finding the IDE that I want to use and yet some more time browsing through opensource projects and I am going nowhere fast! And while everything will be useful at some point if I am maxing 5 hours a day of time invested in learning Php and it is getting split in five it will take me years till I ever(if ever) get somewhere that I can start working! Should I do one thing at a time or maybe assign percentages to learn simultaneously?

I have seen similar questions on SO(which I have waded through) but I think my question is unique in asking how to prioritize and schedule Php with Programming.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You are in "infinite loop" because your aim is about money not about creating a project.

> "If one does not know to which port one is sailing, no wind is
>   favourable." Seneca

**Overall plan:**

> Advanced MP3 Cataloging/Management/Classification system for 
>   **thousands of lectures given by one lecturer** that have no predefined topic and are created on the fly containing multiple
>   **topics** and based on multiple **books** and also have many parts which have to be censored for **certain audiences**.

So what I personally suggest:

make a database using phpmyadmin Designer with logical connections like this:
[image: just an example]
image source: http://thedigitalmachine.com/images/news/phpmyadmin_designer.png
found using [google](http://www.google.hu/search?q=phpmyadmin%20Designer&hl=hu&qscrl=1&site=webhp&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=isch&ei=6EzvTrfzGMWL4gTChPiSCQ&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=2&sqi=2&ved=0CB0Q_AUoAQ&biw=1066&bih=800)
for your own phpmyadmin page ask your server administrator

The possible tables are bold.

After that fill the database width example data, and try manipulate them using mysql_query()-s in php.

**Getting started**

> basic database of all current audio files with basic
>   information such as time, topic,locationetc

1. log in into phpmyadmin
2. create a database called basic_database
3. create a table in basic_database called audio_files width time,topic,locationetc fields

Therse steps are well explained at http://www.shotdev.com/php/php-mysql/php-phpmyadmin-create-database-table/

Comment: I am sorry that I made such an emphasis on earning money. I meant to convey that I just don't have a few years available to learn everything separately and I need to prioritize efficiently and get moving in the next few months. I in fact have a project that is very close to me that I am burning to start with but I am worried that it is much to complicated for my current expertise and I need experts to tell me if it is feasible and what skill level is a prerequisite!

Comment: So you have to tell us your project and according to that we can help more effectively fitting your needs.

Comment: How should I ask? I think it is a complicated project with many parts and you saw how long winded I wrote this question!

Comment: Tell us one part. The first part.

Comment: Should I make a new question because I think here is going to be off topic?

Comment: No this question is OK it shows your "development". That you will be able to focus on one problem.

Comment: Advanced MP3 Cataloging/Management/Classification system for thousands of lectures given by one lecturer that have no predefined topic and are created on the fly containing multiple topics and based on multiple books and also have many parts which have to be censored for certain audiences. The Classification will be Hierarchical Event-SubEvent-SubSubEvent-Topic-SubTopic and the top levels(including SubSubEvent) should be able to link to specific parts of lecture(e.g. between 12:23m-21:45m ).Part 1: basic database of all current audio files with basic information such as time, topic,locationetc

Comment: Sorry cant access the diagram you sent maybe mail me?

Answer (score 2):

I think the following method will help you.

Firstly, start with [Head First PHP & MySQL](http://headfirstlabs.com/books/hfphp/). It allows you to get quick started with basics of PHP and MySQL. Although, it won't cover OOP concepts, you will be ready to start simple projects after this one.

Then, you need to concentrate on OOP concepts. For that, I think [PHP Object-Oriented Solutions](http://www.apress.com/9781430210115) will be of helpful to you. you can skip many things you learn earlier with Head First book.

Now, you need to do some projects. I suggest [PHP Professional Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1931841535).

After you are comfortable with those projects, you can expand your knowledge by studying about PHP frameworks, Templating engines, and PHP patterns. For that, It is better to ask to someone with more knowledge :)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Neyl, you can start PHP using [w3schools PHP tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/).

It has a nice hierarchy in subjects, and examples for each one.

Comment: I have been there, thanks. My question was more related to learning the Programming process together with Php which I don't think they have anything to add

Comment: May you describe your need more? You wrote a long story, but you did not mention to your exact need. Sorry if I could not understand your mean.

Comment: http://w3fools.com - W3Schools encourages bad practices and bad coding. If someone learns everything from W3schools, I would never ever even consider hiring them because I'd expect awful results. Please recommend another set of tutorials.

Comment: ^ @Flukey, w3fools is just a hate page, they say what's wrong (lets assume they're correct), but they don't provide solution.

Comment: No at all. If you read what they say, they're entirely correct. W3schools provides false information and teaches people incredibly bad practices. They're a complete joke and the sooner people stop using them, the better. The solution is simple: use other tutorials or get proper training.